# Webpack security issue - css-loader

Tags: reactjs, webpack

So I've got a suuuuper basic webpack setup for a simple react app. I've been using css-loader to translate my CSS for webpack. But I'm getting a security warning... that seems to have no published solutions.

Here is the warning:

```
│ Critical      │ Command Injection                                            │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ macaddress                                                   │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ No patch available                                           │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ css-loader [dev]                                             │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ css-loader > cssnano > postcss-filter-plugins > uniqid >     │
│               │ macaddress                                                   │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/654
```

As you can see, the issue is not webpack itself, but instead this macaddress package. I'm not sure what to do about this. It says it's "critical".... is there a fix for this? Could I use something other than css-loader?

Here is my full webpack.config.js file:

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin'); 

module.exports={
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/, 
                exclude: [
                    "/node_modules/",
                    "src/tests/"
                ],  
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader"
                }
            }, 
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "style-loader" // creates style nodes for JS strings
                    }, 
                    {
                        loader: "css-loader" // translates CSS into CommonJS
                    }, 
                    {
                        loader: "sass-loader" // compiles Sass to CSS
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/, 
                use: [
                    { 
                        loader: "html-loader" 
                    }
                ]
            }

        ]
    }, 
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
            template: "./public/index.html", // where to read
            filename: "./index.html" // where to put code
        })
    ]
}
```

I just want a working webpack setup with no security issues. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/issues/716

Answer (score 0):

As posted by @David Tyron, there's an issue opened on GitHub and release `2.0.3` should fix it. Try updating.

Comment: Yeah I tried doing "npm update", "npm update macaddress" and "npm update css-loader" Nothing did the trick. It still shows the security issue

Comment: I don't think it's something that influences your app security in the end. The problem is in the module that is supposed to work with MAC addresses, while you're trying to minify css.If it's not blocking your workflow, I'd just ignore it. The warning is in place for nodejs developers, as I unserstand, showing that they can't rely on the lib's code. Don't thik it's really relevant in this case.